# Swing: Is there a way to detect if the mouse is still?

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent

Under MouseInputAdapter, there is a listener for mousePressed, mouseReleased, mouseDragged, and mouseMoved, but is there a listener for when the mouse is still?

Comment: Why? Tell us what your actual requirement is, not your attempted solution and we might be able to provide a different approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such event built in.

If you need that functionality, you may want to consider using a timer. Set the timer to the length of time you want the mouse to be idle before the event is fired. Be sure to reset the timer in the MouseMoved event. You probably want to enable and reset the timer on MouseEnter and disable the timer on MouseLeave.

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no such listener i.e method. It's just that, when none of these events is triggered you may assume the mouse is still.